# Zend Form: How can I show errors after the element's label tag?

Tags: php, zend-form

I can get errors to be shown after the form element, but not directly after the form element's label tag.  Does anyone know how I can do this??  Thx in advance!  Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show errors between the label and the element?

Comment: Thx for the reply, Phil.  I'm looking to show errors after the label but within the definition term tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can do this by altering the Decorator used to render the form elements.

Check here http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

This article will guide you through creating alternate decorators for elements.

Also here is the Zend article on the standard decorators.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html

Comment: Thats the power of the Decorator Pattern.  Very convenient in examples like form markup.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place element errors between the element and its label, keeping the standard dt/dd markup, use something like this

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('Errors', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'))
));
```

The important part is the `'placement' => 'prepend'` on the Errors decorator.

Comment: Phil, what would be the best way to set these decorators to apply to all forms?  Should I extend the Zend_Form::addElement() function with your code?

Comment: @blacktie24 You can use `Zend_Form::setElementDecorators()` to set all element decorators however this may not suit. The other suggestion, whilst fairly long winded is to not only extend `Zend_Form` but all the elements as well. See [here](https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/Form.php) and [here](https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/tree/master/library/Tolerable/Form) for an example

Comment: phil, i can only get it to render as follows:

<dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="required">Email:</label></dt>
<label class="error" generated="true">Value is required and can't be empty</label>
<dd><input name="email" id="email" value="" class="full" type="text"></dd>

I'm trying to get the error message to be inside of the definition term tag.  Is this possible?

Comment: @blacktie24 Using the exact code in my answer, the errors are inside the `<dd>`. Are you saying you want them inside the `<dt>`?

Comment: yes, that's what I was asking, really sorry about the lack of clarity on the question.  However, I was looking through the code and it doesn't seem to be possible without extending the errors & label decorators, is this correct?